# Moving multiple files to different directories via commandline

Tags: windows, command-line

So I'm just experimenting with the command line and was wondering if there was a way to make this command work:

note: the directory where I'm moving these files has the subdirectories bmps, gifs, and tifs already created. I realized earlier that there was no way to create a directory using the move command lol.

```
move swag.gif, swag.bmp, swag.tif bmps, gifs, tifs
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here with these files again? Can you edit your answer so it's more clear what you're trying to accomplish exactly and perhaps with an example such as I need this to go here and here or just here, etc.?

Comment: well basically I was trying to move three different files to three different destinations.
and uhh, Alexey's answer was sufficient enough for me. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do that. Move command syntax does not allow multiple destinations, in your case the destination is `tifs`.

However, you can achieve the effect you want by using `for` command:

```
for %E in (gif bmp tif) do (
    for %F in (*.%E) do echo move %F %Es
)
```

The outer loop specifies the extension in `%E`, then the inner loop iterates over all files which match the pattern `*.%E` where is one of the extensions. The current file name is stored in `%F`. Then the file is moved to the directory `%E` with added `s` creating `gifs`…

*Note:* I added `echo` command to avoid moving the files, instead "move commands" are printed to the screen. Remove `echo` to execute `move`.

---

Another approach is to use special expansion:

```
for %F in (*.gif *.bmp *.tif) do echo move %F %~xFs
```

In this case `%~xF` expands to file extension but with starting `.`: `.gif`. So this solution cannot be used right away. (I didn't find quickly how to remove the dot to get "bare" extension.)